# phpexcel chart file corrupt when outputted to browser

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

I get no `corruption` message when saving the file to server.

But I get `"We found a problem with some content.... "` message when outputting the file to browser.

Data and chart are displayed though.

Here's the code:

```
public function plotChartAndExport($x_data, $y_data, $row_count)
{
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kathmandu');
    define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    for($i=1; $i<=$row_count; $i++) 
    {
        $objWorksheet->setCellValue('A'.$i, $x_data[$i-1]);
        $objWorksheet->setCellValue('B'.$i, $y_data[$i-1]);
    }
    //  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot

    $dataSeriesLabels = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1),   
    );
    //  Set the X-Axis Labels

    $xAxisTickValues = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$'.$row_count, NULL, ($row_count-1)),  
    );
    //  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot

    $dataSeriesValues = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$'.$row_count, NULL, ($row_count-1)),
        );
    //  Build the dataseries
    $series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
    $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
    );
    //  Set additional dataseries parameters
    //  Make it a vertical bar rather than a horizontal column graph
    $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
    //  Set the series in the plot area
    $plotArea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
    //  Set the chart legend
    $legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
    $title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Bar Chart');
    $yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Hours');
    //  Create the chart
    $chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
        'chart1',       // name
        $title,         // title
        $legend,        // legend
        $plotArea,      // plotArea
        true,           // plotVisibleOnly
        0,              // displayBlanksAs
        NULL,           // xAxisLabel
        $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
    );
    //  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
    $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A'.($row_count+2));
    $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');
    //  Add the chart to the worksheet
    $objWorksheet->addChart($chart);

    // // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Test Report.xlsx"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

I have been trying to resolve the issue for some time and it all seems okay.

Why is it causing the file to corrupt when outputting in the browser?

Comment: well, hard to say, without whole code.... i remember the message from my xlsx builds, most time it happens when writing to the same cell a second time or using special chars in the xlsx tabs or using strange cell formatings

Comment: @FatFreddy I have edited the post and added full export code. FYI, there was no such issue with saving to server. And also after recovering the file, data and chart opens fine.

Comment: issue appears, if you have too much values in your $x_data and $y_data. if i addept then     $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A'.($row_count+20)); $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H40'); , no problems with opening, or even more down. Maybe better solution will be , to set the data on one sheet and the chart on a second sheet

Comment: @FatFreddy thank you.. I'll try what you said.

Comment: @FatFreddy trying `$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A'.($row_count+20)); $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H40'); ` still gives the same issue

Comment: how many items are in your $x_data and $y_data ?

Comment: these are dynamically generated records from database query.. but for now.. I've 8 test values in each array..
also, when I try to set title to worksheet chart is shown but empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution to create the chart in a a second sheet, replace the lines in your code:

```
...
    //  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A1');
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');
        //  Add the chart to the worksheet

        $objPHPExcel->createSheet(1);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->setTitle('chart', false);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->addChart($chart);
        // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
...
```

if there is still an issue, check if you send any output to the browser before sending the header.

edit: problem is within the headers. well at least, first try to save the file, then read it:

```
 // Save Excel 2007 file
    $lsFileName = "Test Report.xlsx";
    $lsSavePath = "some/folder/with/permission/to/save/". $lsFileName;

    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->save($lsSavePath);

    $lnFilesize = filesize($lsSavePath);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . utf8_decode($lsFileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header("Content-Length:" . $lnFilesize);
    readfile($lsSavePath);

//     $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: data and chart are rendered in different worksheets but the file still needs to be repaired.
even tried clearing the output buffer before sending the header...

Comment: this solution of first saving file to server itself and reading the file and writing it to output buffer, worked.